# How can I abort all of bulk job at a time

Tags: bulk-api, abortjob

I have a lot of jobs open in Setup -> Bulk Data Load Jobs.
How can I abort them all of them at a time.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to manually abort each record as we do not have any snippet nor any backend process to abort the Bulk jobs altogether.

However, we can abort one job at a time, as per the following document.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/close_job.htm

For further reference, you can check this too,

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315129&type=1&mode=1

I hope it helps.